# Responsive css background images

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image, image-resizing

I have a website (g-floors.eu) and I want to make the background (in css I have defined a bg-image for the content) also responsive. Unfortunately I really don't have any idea on how to do this except for one thing that I can think of but it's quite a workaround. Creating multiple images and then using css screen size to change the images but I wanna know if there is a more practical way in order to achieve this.

Basically what I wanna achieve is that the image (with the watermark 'G') automatically resizes without displaying less of the image. If it's possible of course

link: [g-floors.eu](http://www.g-floors.eu)

Code I have so far (content part)

```css
#content {
  background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
  height: 610px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this link, might it be what you are looking for? http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I feel like this solution that Christofer Vilander posted is a better solution than the chosen answer.

Comment: Just wondering why the site doesn't actually implement this resizing feature you were asking about, as of Feb 2015?  Was there some issue with it?

Answer (score 426, accepted):

If you want the same image to scale based on the size of the browser window:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

Do not set width, height, or margins.

EDIT:
The previous line about not setting width, height or margin refers to OP's original question about scaling with the window size. In other use cases, you may want to set width/height/margins if necessary.

Comment: Is it also possible to auto resize the width and let the height be fixed?

Comment: Yes, you can set the height of the image in pixels and the width in percents, but the image will be destorted. It won't look nice.

Comment: Aah i see because the image i use is a brown background with a light grey 'G' as the watermark (quite large) so i want that to resize but thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: You can use a much smaller image if you use a vector format: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics

Comment: Should this work with data URI as well ? When I replaced "background-image:url('../images/bg.png');" with a data uri, something like: "background-image:url("data:image/gif;base64,R0....no-repeat scroll center center / contain  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");" it doesn't seem to work in Chrome.

Comment: What? Not setting width, height to the container won't show the image at all.

Comment: @snow: No one is suggesting that a container should not have height. Width is optional as most block elements (e.g. `div`) default to 100%.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin then what does `Do not set height` mean?

Comment: (1) The original question was about scaling based on a browser window size. (2) Elements like `div` get their own height from their own content, or take available space in a flexbox model. Saying that without explicit width/height the container won't show at all is incorrect. Obviously, if you want to display an empty div with a background image, you will need to set the height and, possibly, width, but then you will see only a part of an image, unless the aspect ratio is exactly the same as of the image itself.

Comment: Not setting width, height to the container won't show the image at all

Comment: @IshanPatel: There are many ways in which a container may get its size, and explicit height and width is only one of them. You may want to learn a bit more about layouts before downvoting a response that 300 other people upvoted :)

Comment: A way to ensure the image displays as long as the parent div has width or height is to set the `width: inherit` and `height: inherit`

Comment: I am going to cry. Thank you!
Just do not forget to to set width and height

Comment: @ErikRybalkin: An element can get its width and height in other ways - for example, from its children or from its parent. Setting width and height explicitly is just one of possible options.

Answer (score 81):

by this code your background image go center and fix it size whatever your div size change , good for small , big , normal sizes , best for all , i use it for my projects where my background size or div size can change

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
```

Comment: At screen size 800x1280px, the image gets cut off on the right side by the box.  All the other sizes seem fine.

Answer (score 69):

Try this :

```
background-image: url(_images/bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 37):

CSS:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

That should do the trick! :)

Comment: This will totally distort the image based on the browser window aspect ratio. Never do it.

Comment: Just for future reference, it actually won't look bad this way. background-size: 100% 100% would, but declaring only the x as 100% keeps it from looking terrible. Test case: http://codepen.io/howlermiller/pen/syduB

Comment: it won't look "distorted" but it will stretch the image beyond its intended proportions if it is smaller than the container...

Comment: So will the accepted answer. The OP didn't ask about that problem, just whether it was possible to make it resize nicely.

Comment: For top logo: backgorund-size:100%;background-position:top; padding-bottom:img-height/img-width x 100 = X%.

Comment: The trick doesn't work entirely for resizing when you expect responsiveness from both width/height dimensions.

Answer (score 23):

Here is sass mixin for responsive background image that I use. It works for any `block` element. Of course the same can work in plain CSS you will just have to calculate `padding` manually.

```
@mixin responsive-bg-image($image-width, $image-height) {
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: percentage($image-height / $image-width);
  display: block;
}


.my-element {
  background: url("images/my-image.png") no-repeat;

  // substitute for your image dimensions
  @include responsive-bg-image(204, 81);
}
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/XbEdW/1/

Comment: the code in the fiddle (uses a framework) is different than the code in the answer.

Answer (score 22):

### This is an easy one =)

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://domains.com/photo.jpeg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Take a look at the [**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/2raxtxqr/15/)

Answer (score 14):

Here is the best way i got.

```
#content   {
    background-image:url('smiley.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Check on the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=auto)

More Available options

```
background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit;
```

Answer (score 13):

```
#container {
    background-image: url("../images/layout/bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 3px auto 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This works for me without `relative` Thank you man.

Answer (score 10):

I used

```
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

which worked really well.

Comment: That is the code I needed! Thanks :)) I'm trying to do parallax on 100% of the screen but 200px height and I need only the top part of the background but keeping the proportions of the whole image.

Answer (score 6):

Responsive website by add padding into bottom image height/width x 100 = padding-bottom %:

http://www.outsidethebracket.com/responsive-web-design-fluid-background-images/

---

More complicated method:

http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios

---

Try to resize background eq Firefox Ctrl + M to see magic nice script i think best one:

http://www.minimit.com/demos/fullscreen-backgrounds-with-centered-content

Answer (score 5):

You can use this. I have tested and its working 100% correct:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
background-position:center;
```

You can test your website with responsiveness at this Screen Size Simulator:
    http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php

Clear Your cache each time you make changes and i would prefer to use Firefox to test it.

If you want to use an Image form other site/URL and not like:
`background-image:url('../images/bg.png');`
//This structure is to use the image from your own hosted server.
Then use like this:
`background-image: url(http://173.254.28.15/~brettedm/wp-content/uploads/Brett-Edmonds-Photography-14.jpg) ;`

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 5):

```
    <style> 
         * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#res_img {
  background: url("https://s15.postimg.org/ve2qzi01n/image_slider_1.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:500px) {
  #res_img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
}

    </style>

<div id="res_img">
</div>
```

Comment: Surprised to see this was the only answer even mentioning @media queries - which was very surprising given the subject of responsive css. If your image is large (in file size) you can create different sizes of it and add different `background` properties for each increasing resolution. That way you're not downloading a huge image on a small phone.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the entire image to show irrespective of the aspect ratio, then try this:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
background-position:center;
```

This will show the entire image no matter what the screen size.

Answer (score 3):

```
background:url("img/content-bg.jpg") no-repeat;
background-position:center; 
background-size:cover;
```

or

```
background-size:100%;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just two lines of code, it works.

```
#content {
  background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
background: url(/static/media/group3x.6bb50026.jpg);
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top;
```

the position property can be used to align top bottom and center as per your need and background-size can be used for center crop(cover) or full image(contain or 100%)

Answer (score 2):

Adaptive for square ratio with jQuery

```
var Height = $(window).height();
var Width = $(window).width();
var HW = Width/Height;

if(HW<1){
      $(".background").css("background-size","auto 100%");
    }
    else if(HW>1){
      $(".background").css("background-size","100% auto");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way to do it is this:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    background:url("/images/image.jpg") no-repeat fixed bottom right transparent;
}
```

In this way there's no need to do nothing more and it's quite simple.

At least, it works for me.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-size` but using **TWO ARGUMENTS** One for the width and the other one for the height

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%; // Here the first argument will be the width 
// and the second will be the height.
background-position:center;
```