# Responsive background image issue

Tags: image

Ive been following example after example on different sites and cant seem to make them work 100%
Using the examples on this post: [Responsive css background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)

background-size:contain makes the image really small in the centre of the div and background-size:cover makes the image full size but chopped off top and bottom unless the browser is resized and it gets better as you resize smaller

```
{
    background-image:url('logo2.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size:contain;
    -moz-background-size:contain;
    -o-background-size:contain;
}
```

http://www.techagesite.com/page-1work11122.htm