# Responsive header image

Tags: css

I´m making a prestashop store and I already include one image into the header bur the image isn´t responsive. How can I make de image responsive?

Look the code of the header image:

```
header {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF url('http://s23.postimg.org/ha3x2zf23/header_image1_sized.jpg')!important;
  padding-bottom: 100px; }
```

Anyone can help me to change the code to put a responsive image in header?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive css background images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)

Comment: `background-size:contain;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-size:contain;` and assign size for email in percentage or em (this it is up to you).

Please test it here
http://jsbin.com/zohinomiya/1/
and try to re-sizing your browser window to see the scaling.

```
<! doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
    #test {
        background-image: url('http://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image2.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:contain;
        background-position:center;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <script>

    </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id ="test">s</div>
        </body>
</html>
```