# Scaling background with image

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-sprites

I have an element that is using image as a background. The image is part of a larger image containing sprites. I need to scale down that element for responsive reasons, is it possible to scale the image accordingly or do I have to add alternative smaller image to the sprite?

```
<div class="sprites casa_48"></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/54wd345j/)

Comment: could you prepare a minimal working example on codepen or jsfiddle with the actual image and the result you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images/12609315#12609315  You can use this technique with sprites too.

Comment: Isn't that example for a single background image? I use sprites and they are not in a single file vertically or horizontally. Kind of like this: http://zerosprites.com/detail/guh3a/