# How can we resize (make smaller) background image of a div in smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, css

we have a div with a background image. We want to make the image smaller, not to exceed the parent div. Right now, because the image is too big, it comes out of the parent div. I tried max-width:100%;height:auto and display:block; like I saw in another thread but didnt worked.
can someone help me?
thank you in advanced

Comment: We need to see your HTML & CSS code but I think you should be looking at `background-size` for a **background-image**.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
```

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023286/2257396).