# How to make a background-image on a image responsive

Tags: html, css, background

How do I get my `#img-alfa` image responsive?
I already tried `background-size:100% auto;` and if I delete the `width` and `height` of the `background-image` it totally disappears.

```css
.img-responsive {
 width: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#img-alfa {
top: -60px;
left: 68px;
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
background: url("../img/alfazwartwitsmall2.png") no-repeat;
 }
 
#img-alfa:hover {
top: -60px;
left: 68px;
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
background: url("../img/alfakleursmall2.png") no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
 <img class="img-responsive"
    src="img/background_white.jpg">
 <span class="circle_inner">  
<a href="#"><div style="border-radius: 0em;" class="img-responsive" id="img-alfa" ></div></a>
    </span>
 </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `background-size: cover`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive css background images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)

Comment: Yes, already tried that, also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `background-size: cover;`, with a trick to keep your image ratio:

```css
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#img-alfa {
  padding-bottom: 75%; /* See comments under snippet */
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/g/200/150");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://placekitten.com/200/150">
<div class="img-responsive" id="img-alfa"></div>
```

The trick is to use a percent value for `padding-bottom`. The value will be calculated, **based on the width value** (= 100%). Here how to define the `75%` value:

> padding-bottom = 100 * height / width = 100 * 150 / 250 = 75

Comment: Responsive image are supposed to always be 100% width. You should change your container size instead of.

Comment: in css comments should be like `/* comment */`

Comment: Woops! I don't use CSS anymore, only Sass... My bad.