# Making background image responsive in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to create a responsive website from scratch without using any frameworks like bootstrap. i had a banner in my website for which i had set background image as follows

```
<body>
    <div id="pagewrap">
        <div class="test">
            <div class="headers">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Site Logo"/></a>
                </div><!--logo-->
                <div class="nav"></div><!--nav-->
                <div class="slider_content"></div><!--slider_content-->
            </div><!--header-->
        </div>
    </div><!--pagewrap-->
</body>
```

```css
.headers {
    background-image:url(images/banner.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    width:100%;
}
```

When I apply height to the `div` headers image gets displayed but it is taking the same height in mobile devices too which doesn't look good. How do I make this responsive so that the background image scales according to the device resolution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive css background images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)

Comment: @Persijn i tried the solution explained there without setting any height or width.  but unfortunately its not working

Answer (score 1):

Might this will help you, [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/efpo5qfu/)

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var imgHeight = $( window ).height(),
      imgWidth = $( window ).width();
    $('.headers').css({
        height: imgHeight,
        width: imgWidth
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try applying padding percentages instead of a fixed height.

So `padding-bottom:50%;` and change cover to `background-size:100% auto;`

let me know how it goes I think this is how I got round it before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to work with percentage values? Something like height 100%
Or you can experiment with the vh-attribute. but when you want to work with vh, make sure you're using jQuery too because of the browser-support:

```
var viewHeight = $( window ).height();
  $('.element').css('height', viewHeight);
```