# CSS: How to make responsive background image that excluded the aspect ratio of the image?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a background image in the body that won't maintain the aspect ratio of the ratio.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/xmasbg13.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The code above works fine if the browser window is in full screen. But when I resize the browser, it maintains the aspect ratio of the image and won't cover the whole page.

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images

Comment: use `background-size: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

How about `background-size:cover`

http://jsfiddle.net/2ez1e3mn/

You can resize the results pane and the image resizes (full height and width) with it.

Comment: hmmmm... background-size:cover should ignore aspect ratio. Do you have a working URL that illustrates the problem?

Comment: oh! I solved it now. I just remove the `height:100%`.