# Bootstrap image not responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am adding a  logo using bootstrap etc and a background image. I'm not sure if I am doing this right but when I resize the window the nav bar it self is getting smaller but the image in the navbar is not. Anyone know why?

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="Image/Logo.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>       
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Become A member</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body { 
    background: url('../Image/BackgroundImage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin-top: 60px;
    height: 80px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: normal normal normal 12px/1.3em 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
     padding:28px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus{
    color: #ffcb80;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffcb80;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.logo {
    margin-left: 4em;
}
```

So its my logo div which is not re-sizing at the moment. Also I have a question about my background image, usually they don't need to resize? Mine just cuts out and you only see bits of it, is that good etc? or bad coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make images responsive within the Bootstrap Framework you need to add a class to the image tag:

- class="img-responsive"

See bootstraps documentation for further details here:

- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

**Example:**

```
<img src="Image/Logo.png" class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: That is fantasti , thank u very much for the help, do i need to do this for the background image is well?

Comment: This may be of help regarding the CSS background image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images