# Responsive background issue

Tags: css, background-image

What I need is responsive full background image via CSS, say like [there](http://sailingcollective.com/).

I've read lots of cases here and saw also one of the "best answers" to the topic
[Responsive css background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)

But I still can't find an appropriate solution to me.
[Here's my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmpes2pv/2/)

And code:

```
.container {
 background-image: url(http://www.spektyr.com/PrintImages/Cerulean%20Cross%203%20Large.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-position: center;
 height: 700px;
```

}

Without setting any height as recommended in the answer above the image doesn't appear at all. And when I resize the window to smaller, the image gets some space above instead of fitting the window every time.

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**

After hours of experiments it came to solution to use **padding-top** property instead of setting **height**

Comment: Use `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: Does my answer give you the expected result?!

Comment: @John Slegers
Both Yes and No. Yes - it "behaves" a bit better, No - it is still gotten cropped when comes about 40% of my browser window when I resize it.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov : That's because you set a fixed height. You need to remove the height and replace it with a 100% based padding.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov : I just updated my answer. Does it now give you the expected result?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    background-image: url(http://www.spektyr.com/PrintImages/Cerulean%20Cross%203%20Large.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 100%; /* <- This value should be equal to height / width */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Something</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cmpes2pv/12/))

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`background-size:cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) on `.container` like:

```
.container {
  background-image: url(http://www.spektyr.com/PrintImages/Cerulean%20Cross%203%20Large.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 700px;
}
```

> A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom.<sup>[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)</sup>

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ym76faL4/)

### Edit:

If, as you indicated in the comments below, you want the full image to be displayed, regardless of the the screen size, use [`background-size:contain;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

```
.container {
  background-image: url(http://www.spektyr.com/PrintImages/Cerulean%20Cross%203%20Large.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: contain;
  height: 700px;
}
```

> A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed within the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are filled with the background-color.  The image is automatically centered unless over-ridden by another property such as background-position.<sup>[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)</sup>

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ym76faL4/)

Comment: If we set "background-size: cover" it won't help the situation. Because if you resize the window to smaller, there's a breakpoint when the image stops being resized and gets cropped. I've just checked.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov so you want the image to be fully displayed, but not distorted, no matter the screen size?

Comment: Exactly! Imagine it as the same image every time which is only being scaled but not cropped when you resize the window.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov Updated the answer

Comment: "background-position: contain" must work as I had though too, but indeed it makes the image uncover the div + adds some space around when we resize to smaller.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov that's what's going to happen with any solution. If you want to preserve the aspect ration of the image(not distort), then you will either crop areas out of the image on certain screen sizes, or the image not cover parts of the element on certain screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways come to mind depending on your end goal. The first is to use `background-size: cover;`, which will keep the aspect ratio, but could cause your background image to pixelate if you have a low-resolution image. The other is to use `background-size: 100% 100%;`. Note that in your fiddle, you have simple `100%`. By adding it 2 times, forces both the X and Y axes to span 100% of the screen.

Fiddle for `cover`: https://jsfiddle.net/eqe3m2sn/1/

Fiddle for `100% 100%`: https://jsfiddle.net/nmofhodo/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `background-position: center;` to `background-position: top;` and it will fill the space above on resize. As for the size, I'm pretty sure you need to set the height when working with background pictures.

Hope that helps!