# Dynamically set background-image-url

Tags: css, gwt, background-image

In my gwt-application i got a tree with a few images. These images can be copied by drag and drop to a panel. Now i want to make them resizable in this panel. when i test my css-code with a concrete image-path for "background-image", resize:both and background-size:cover works! My problem is, that i cannot set a concrete url to the css, becacuse the imagepath is dynamic.
when i delete background-image from css and set backgroundimage in my code, the surrounding container resizes, but the image not. Is it possible to set 'background-image' to the image that I choose during runtime? how can i solve that with css?
Thank you!!

Comment: Can you show some code? I can say things like, set `background-size` to `contain` or `cover` (whatever fits your needs), but whether that will work or not depends on what you have already.

Comment: background-size is not the problem... when i test my css-code with a concrete image-path for "background-image", it works! but the problem is, that i cannot set a concrete url to the css, beacuse the imagepath is dynamic... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set background image at any time in your code. For example:

```
myPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage("url(/myImage.jpg)");
```

To make it resizable, you need to apply [the correct CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images/12609315#12609315) to this panel. There are several CSS options for you to consider.

Comment: when i test my css-code with a concrete image-path for "background-image", resizing works! but the problem is, that i cannot set a concrete url to the css, beacuse the imagepath is dynamic... :( how can i solve that in css?

Comment: You can't do it in CSS. You need to use the code that I provided to set the path when you know it.

Comment: okay, but how do i set url dyamic?

>myPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage("url(?)");

Comment: I don't understand your question. Just replace "?" with the URL that you are trying to set. And when you get a new one, call this line of code again with the new URL. Etc.

Comment: Let me try to explain my problem better:)
in a scroll panel i got a tree with a few image-widgets.
When one of these widgets is dragged and dropped to its target=(absolute panel), the original-widget is replaced by a widget-copy.
In the target the dropped widget should be resizable. When i add css with resize-property, the resize-symbol in the corner is shown. I can pull it, but the widget is not resizing, just a „border“ surrounding the widget.