# Background image not really responsive

Tags: css, image, background, responsive

There's a link to my test page [Link](http://jsbin.com/keqawosihe/edit?html,output)

The problem is when I try to resize to small devices, background image is not covering the page properly, image is missing on the bottom of the page.

My CSS in head section.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions what I did wrong.

Comment: `background-size:100%`

Comment: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)..

Comment: no that won't work @GauravAggarwal

Comment: why you have height:135%, make it auto plz

Comment: @czucz did you check the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
html,body {
        height: 135%;
    }
```

to

```
html,body {
        height: auto;
    }
```

Don't use fix height, use auto.