# Responsive Background Image for body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently design a web page using `Bootstrap 3.3.7`.

I want to use an image for body that be responsive. When user change window size, the size of image also change.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following on body.

```
background-image:url('image.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

And do not set any height or width for the image.

Comment: Copy-Paste http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images