# Background img responsive using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I set responsive background image using bootstrap?
i can responsive only image using class="responsive-img" but when I put my image link on css then what can I do?
(sorry for my bad english)
Here is my html and css code-

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

.header-img{background:url("images/header.jpg");
            width:100%;
            height:400px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 
    <head>
        <title>SajidurShajib.com</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">   
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!--header section start here-->
      
        <div class="header-img">
            
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images

Comment: Thanks buddy@Black Bird... :D