# Image declared in css is not showing

Tags: html, css

I want a image to fill the browsers and these are html side code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

since I want the image to be occupied fully in screen i declared it inside the body in css like this but sadly image is not appearing in the screen

```
body{
    background-image:url('../img/bgmapsimage.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}
```

yes the image name is correct and location is correct as well.This is the link i refered [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)

Comment: any errors on console? any content in `<body>`?

Comment: At first check your image path, Is it correctly located?

Comment: @SumonSarker image path,image location,image extension everything works fine the image even display if  height: 500px; is fixed in css

Comment: Your image should be larger for wide screen. I added an answer. You can check it. @GladwinJames

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
body{ 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can also use `vh` to have full height image no matter the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

To test your CSS, try to change the URL in this line

```
background-image:url('../img/bgmapsimage.png');
```

to an absolute URL of which you know it will work, like

```
background-image:url('http://placehold.it/400x300');
```

If this image is shown, your original image path is the problem (the folder structure which your HTML, CSS and image files are in). If it's not shown, most likely your CSS code itself is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your body element is empty and therefore has no height.
if you add a minimum height, you'll see the image:

```
body{
    background-image:url('../img/bgmapsimage.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update your CSS as like below**

```
body{ 
    background: url('../img/bgmapsimage.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: center;
    -moz-background-size: center;
    -o-background-size: center;
    background-size: center;
}
```

**OR**

```
body{ 
    background: url('../img/bgmapsimage.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can also add css for `html` tag

**Example**

```
html{
 /*Your CSS*/
}
```

Here is some CSS tricks for full screen background image [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    //backround image and all
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Though it depends on the size of the image you are working with.