# changing background image header with css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i'm a novice to css, and currently trying using Hotel Master wordpress theme.

I'm trying to change the header background image, but the theme doesn't have the option to change it (only changing color option). so i'll have to change it manually by using additional css style.

could you please tell me what to write on additional css style section ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
.header_section {
  background-image: url("http://www.yourimage.com") !important;
}
```

You can check this out.

Comment: I check on your theme you are using, the team supporters said that you can only change by above code because they don't support that option on their theme. You can check more about css background here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images

Comment: hi, i found an option to change the header background image already, but it turned out it's changing the area under the main navigation menu (home, about, etc).

while, what i originally wanted was to change the background area of the main navigation menu. (change it from plain color to patterned background image) 

https://ibb.co/mbEgQF