# How to align a background image in the center and let it keep its size when responsive

Tags: css, image, background, center

I have been busy at this for too long. Have looked at other questions and answers and NONE of them seem to help me. Tried very many things.

What I want is to have a background image in the middle of the screen and when you make the browser smaller, the image should keep its size and stay in the middle of the screen, so the left AND right site of the background should fall out of the screen and the middle stays visable.
p.s. I do see that the image gets cropped vertically a little bit too.

For example: http://www.jandekeyzer.be/
The slider background image does exactly what I want to have... What is the trick to do this.

Background-position center center, etc, does not do the trick. I am missing something.
I have the code in the style.css. At this moment (since it didnt help) I stripped it down to only
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center; (but even this does nothing).

Who can help me?

Comment: could you please put your code on a fiddle or something to see what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-size: cover;`

> Use cover background size property to resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges

Answer (score 0):

You can try using any of the below to properties:

1) `background-size: contain;`
background-size: contain ensures that the entire background image will fit the background area, keeping its original aspect ratio. if the area is small, it will shrink the image and make it fit, if its larger than the image, it will fill the gaps,by repeating the images , which can be prevented using background:no-repeat

2) `background-size: cover;`
this will fill the entire background area, without any gaps.

You can checkout this link for more solutions:
**[Responsive background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
background-attachment: fixed;  
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please check the [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide so you can better improve your answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, if I understood your question. then it will work. try this**

```
.Selector{      
   background-image: url('../images/image.jpg'); // Background Image (Set location) 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;  // Never repeat
   background-size: cover;        // Keep size cover
   background-position: center;   // Set image postion center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is something in the code holding it from doing what I want. Is there someone who could have a look at the code if I email it?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for thinking with me. But unfortunately i does not resolve it.
Tried it all now.

```
background: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
position: relative;
min-height:700px;
```

It will just not go to the middle, but keeps align left. 
Only when deleting all lines and putting background-size: 100%; the background stays in the middle. But yes, it loses its size when making the browser smaller.

Comment: Please put your updates in the comments to the corresponding answers or as amendments to your original question rather than creating them as an answer, thanks!