# Image not responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I am new to CSS. I have added the code in to make the image responsive, but when I switch to mobile view, the image is not adjusting.

Here is my css -

```
element.style {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-image: url(dummy/banner_wide.png);
```

Not sure what is wrong?

Comment: You are complaining about the image not being responsive. You actually don't have an image, but a **background image**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive css background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)

Comment: So how do I make a background image responsive?

Comment: Refer to that previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images

Comment: Like i said, I am new to CSS. I didn't know it was due to the background-image. Thank you for the link but why give my post negative rating, due to a misunderstanding???

Comment: I have seen other users who have posted the same question but got not negative rating. THIS IS UNFAIR!! Sort it out and remove the negative ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add this in the head tag of html?

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```