# How to set jumbotron to be responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to set jumbotron to be responsive on mobile device it so hard to me.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("../images/cover.fw.png");
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="jumbotron">

  </div>
</header>
```

**Desktop View:**

[image: Desktop View]

**Phone View:**

[image: Phone View]

I need help to accomplish this task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images

Comment: could you please add image path so it will be visible on preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing background-size from `cover` to `contain` will solve the problem.

```
.jumbotron {

  /* other properties */

  background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
}
```

---

**Info**:

`contain` - Resize the background image to make sure the image is fully visible.

`cover` - Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the image responsive without cutting the sides, set **"background-size: contain"**.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmAwL.png");
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="jumbotron"></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

make the background-size: contain instead of cover in the media query and change the height according to the screen in media screen and it works fine