# How to make image responsive which was added using background-image: url(../img/header1.jpg); tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have added an image using css `background-image: url(../img/header1.jpg);` and I want to make it responsive on small devices.

When I inspect and select small devices from responsive there the image get vanished:

[image]

Comment: Can you share any code snippet or fiddle link for more clarifications? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive css background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)

Comment: Sir its ok large devices but when i change it from large to small device 
it did't not show img

Comment: just use `background-size:contain;`

Comment: did you tried `@media` for image in css

Comment: no i did't tried @media query 
i'm trying it now

Comment: Thanks alot sir  it was media querie issue
now it done.