# Background Image Display in Viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a background image that covers the screen. When the viewport shrinks, the view shrinks towards the top left of the image. Is there a way to shrink the viewport towards the center of the background?

```
<section class="hero">

</section>
```

```
.hero {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('img/myimg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: provide the code then  we will able to answer it

Comment: @AbhishekPakhare added a basic example of what I have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive css background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images)

Comment: @vSR3P Yes, thank you. I tried to look in several posts but this was the first one to have "background-position: center".